# Best way to do smooth motion for an Image

Tags: javascript, drawing, html5-canvas

I wrote a quick program to bounce a ball on the screen. Everything works, but the image is prone to flickering and is not smooth.

I suspect that the image flickers because the velocity is significant at the bottom of the screen.

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how to interpolate the motion of the ball to reduce the flicker.

Called to update the position

```
      this.step = function()
      {
        thegame.myface.y = thegame.myface.y + thegame.myface.vSpeed;
        if (thegame.myface.y > thegame.height)
        {
        thegame.myface.vSpeed = -thegame.myface.vSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
        thegame.myface.vSpeed = thegame.myface.vSpeed + 1;
        }
      }
  },
```

Called to redraw

```
draw: function()
      {
          //clears the canvas
          thegame.ctx.clearRect(0,0,thegame.width,thegame.height);
          //draw the objects
          thegame.ctx.drawImage(thegame.imgFace,this.x-this.width/2,this.y-this.height/2);
          return;
      },
```

Call framework in `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
thegame.init(450,450);
// http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating
(function()
 {
 var lastTime = 0;
 var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
 for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x)
 {
 window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
 window.cancelRequestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
 }
 if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
 {
 var f = function(callback, element)
 {
 var currTime = new Date().getTime();
 var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16-(currTime-lastTime));
 var id = window.setTimeout(function()
     {
     callback(currTime+timeToCall);
     }, timeToCall);
 lastTime = currTime+timeToCall;
 return id;
 };
window.requestAnimationFrame = f;
 }
if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id)
    {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
 }());
(function gameloop()
 {
 thegame.update();
 requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
 thegame.draw();
 })();
</script>
```

edit definition for `thegame`

```
   init: function(width, height)
   {
       var canvas = $("<canvas width='"+width+"' height='"+height+"'></canvas>");
       canvas.appendTo("body");
       thegame.ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
       thegame.width = width;
       thegame.height = height;
       thegame.imgFace = new Image();
       thegame.imgFace.src = "face.png";
       thegame.myface = new thegame.makeFace(width/2,height/2);
   },
```

Comment: Try clearing just the ball? http://jsperf.com/canvas-clear-speed/16

Comment: There is not enough code shown here. `thegame` definition would help. When you have flickering, it tends to be because the time to step is slow, and the step distance is large. You should try to fine tune a balance between updating the ball, and moving it (perhaps a smaller distance but a quicker update time). Remember, the ball *does not* have to move in whole numbers, it can be rendered at partial pixel distances.

Comment: Maybe you need double buffering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about visual perception. First find out at what rate the game loop is called by the browser via requestanimationframe. If it's Chrome its task manager will help. If not, calc the rate by yourself with timestamps. It should be at least 60 times per second. If the browser is running at this rate and the movement is still not smooth, the speed is simply too high for that rate.

However, you have options to trick the perception of motion. One is to make the image smaller (simple), another is motion blur (complicated). To do the latter, you basically run the game hidden at double speed and draw two blended frames onto the visible canvas. Or at same speed and a bit simpler, keep track of the last two images and draw both with 50% alpha at the canvas. If you want more background info follow the discussion why latest hobbit movie was filmed at 48 instead of the usual 24 frames per second.

If it appears the image is horizontally chopped/cut in half then the browser is not properly synchronized to the monitor. In this case make sure the vertical sync (vsync) isn't overridden somewhere by the system or display options.

Answer (score 0):

How large is your canvas? Not sure if it will solve your flicker issue, but an additional optimization you can try is to modify your clearRect() call to only clear the region which is dirty, before each update.

Ex: thegame.ctx.clearRect(this.x-this.width/2, this.y-this.height/2, thegame.imgFace.width, thegame.imgFace.height);